# When I use Proc Freq I want to show observations with frequencies of zero

Tags: sas

I am trying to perform frequency analyses on test scores.
My data set has students with recorded scores.

Like below:

```
student,  score

1,           1

2,           1

3,           1

4,           3

5,           3

6,           3

7,           4

8,           4

9,           4

10,          4
```

I run the code:

```
proc freq data=stuff;
var score;
run;
```

The output:

```
score, freq, pct, cum.freq., cum.pct.

1,      3,    .3,    3,        .3

3,      3,    .3,    6,        .6

4,      4,    .4,    10,        1
```

I would like to show:

```
score, freq, pct, cum.freq., cum.pct.

1,      3,    .3,    3,        .3

2,      0,     0,    3,        .3

3,      3,    .3,    6,        .6

4,      4,    .4,    10,        1

5,      0,     0,    10,        1
```

Is there a way that SAS can do this?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can your format your data to show your output and input more clearly? I'd do it, but I'm not sure because your first score (1) only shows a count of 3 but you have 4 in your sample data.

Comment: I don't have time to answer fully, but if someone else doesn't look into the preloadfmt option. You still have to know all levels ahead of time so I don't really like this method, but if it doesn't exist in the data how is the computer supposed to know it exists at all.

Comment: The marked duplicate answers this pretty well and explains the method Reeza's alluding to.  I think for the appropriate cases (such as above with 5 levels) this makes sense; for cases with many levels you can create the format from data or in a programmatic method.

Comment: @Joe, unfortunately I don't think this counts as a duplicate, as `proc tabulate` [cannot produce cumulative statistics](https://communities.sas.com/message/17051).

Comment: If that's important I don't mind reopening, but I don't see that as clearly important from the question (the question just displays the default output from proc freq).

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way. Here are a few approaches. They either involve building the table by hand or preprocessing the input before asking SAS to summarise.

**These will be used as inputs in the approaches below**

```
/* Your input data */
data have;
    infile datalines dlm = ",";
    input student score;
    datalines;
1,1
2,1
3,1
4,3
5,3
6,3
7,4
8,4
9,4
10,4
;
run;
%let max = 5;
/* Create a dummy set of all the desired groups */
data numbers;
    do score = 1 to &max;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

**This approach adds dummy values to the original data and uses `proc freq`'s weight function to decide which rows should contribute to the count** (I prefer this method)

```
/* Combine the inputs and add weight variable */
data input;
    set 
        have (in = a) 
        numbers;
    /* Set weight so that empty groups won't be counted */
    weight = ifn(a, 1, 0)
run;
/* Create the report */
proc freq data = input;
    table score;
    /* Only add to the count when weight = 1, include 0 rows */
    weight weight / zeros;
run;
```

**This approach builds the table by hand**

```
/* Get the total count and each group's count */
proc summary data = have;
    class score;
    output out = counts;
run;
/* Combine and create the summary stats */
data want;
    merge 
        counts (rename = (_FREQ_ = freq)) 
        numbers;
    by score;
    /* Keep the total and cumulative total when new rows are loaded */
    retain total cumsum;
    /* Set up the total and delete the total row */
    if _TYPE_ = 0 then do; 
        total = freq;
        delete;
    end;
    /* Prevent missing values by adding 0 */
    freq + 0;
    /* Calculate stats */
    pct = freq / total; 
    cumsum + freq;
    cumpct = cumsum / total;
    drop _TYPE_ total;
run;
proc print;run;
```

**This approach modifies the `proc freq` output to add in the extra rows**

```
/* Create the frequency report as a dataset */
proc freq data = have;
    table score;
    /* Output as dataset */
    ods output OneWayFreqs = freqs (drop = table f_score);
run;
/* Combine and build the extra rows */
data want (drop = _:);
    merge 
        freqs (in = f)
        numbers;
    by score;
    /* Set up temporary variables for storing cumulatives */
    retain _lp _lf;
    /* Store cumulatives */
    if f then do;
        _lf = CumFrequency;
        _lp = CumPercent;
    end;
    /* Put stored values into new rows */
    else do;
        Frequency = 0;
        Percent = 0;
        CumFrequency = _lf;
        CumPercent = _lp;
    end;
run;
proc print; run;
```

Using Joe's suggestion above will also get you part of the way, but unfortunately cannot compute the cumulative columns. 
**This is a partial solution using Joe's method**

```
/* Create a format showing each of the desired levles */
proc format;
    value score
        1='1'
        2='2'
        3='3'
        4='4'
        5='5';
quit;
proc tabulate data = have;
    /* Specify that every formatted value should be included */
    class score / preloadfmt;
    /* Apply the format */
    format score score.;
    tables score, 
        /* Request the output table include frequency and percent */
        (n="freq" pctn="cumfreq" ) / 
        /* Include missings and display them as 0s */
        printmiss misstext="0";
run;
```